How to Connect to MySQL Server and access a pre-defined database from Remote Host in PHP?
I have different PHP files set up, along with an HTML file, of which my 1st PHP "signguestbook.php" seeks to connect to a remote MySQL database that's within a MySQL database server of which the database connection fails to establish over and over again. My PHP file, 'signguestbook.php', contains the code necessary to perform this function, as I want my program to (upon having the user input their credentials in my 'guestbook.html' file, use a pre-set MySQL database to create a table to enter in the user details. Unfortunately, this results in a blank webpage for the "signguestbook.php", in which I get an error message saying "HTTP ERROR 500", along with "www.remotesite.com is currently unable to handle this request".
signguestbook.php
if (empty($_POST['first_name']) || empty($_POST['last_name'])) { // checks if firstname and lastname fields are empty
    echo "<p align='center' >You must enter your first name and last name. Click your browser's Back button to return to the Guest Book form</p>";
} 
else {
    $user = "aCegikmoqsuwy"; // username provided by my administrator
    $password = "a1b2c3d4e5f6"; // password provided by my administrator
    $host = "www.remotesite.com"; // hostname of web server, but hostname for mysql user is "localhost'?

    $DBconnect = @mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password); // creates the database connection
    if ($DBconnect === FALSE) {
        echo "<p>ERROR. Unable to connect to the server.</p>" . "<p>Error code" . mysqli_errno() . ":" . mysqli_error() . "</p>";
    } else { 
        $DBName = "aCegikmoqsuwy_block1"; // pre-defined database, can only create tables within it
        if (!@mysqli_select_db($DBconnect, $DBName)) { // verifies whether database is not exited
            $SQLString = "USE DATABASE $DBName"; // This command uses this MySQL database
            $QueryResult = @mysqli_query($DBconnect, $SQLString);

I have my HTML code in a separate file, called guestbook.html:
<html>
<title>
    Guest Book
</title>
<body>
<h2 align="center">Please enter your name to sign our Guest Book.<h2>
        <form method="POST" action="signguestbook.php">
            <table align="center">
                <tr>
                    <td>First Name:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="first_name" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Last Name:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="last_name" />
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan=2 align="center"><input type="Submit" value="Submit" />
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
        <p align="center"><a href="showguestbook.php">Show Guest Book</a>
</body>
</html>

I use VS Code to connect to the remote web server via SSH (with my hostname as "www.remotesite.com", username, and password credentials). I also use MobaXterm to not only setup a session via SSH  (with the same credentials mentioned before), but I also use the "mysql -u username -p" command (password is same as that used to login into session via SSH) to enter into the MySQL command line, where I can actually access the database and create tables and perform queries there. Yet, my code that I showed above already has commands designed to do this. Anyone knows what I'm doing wrong, and how to solve this issue?

500 Internal Server error is a deliberately vague error message intended to tell the user that there is a server fault without leaking sensitive information. Look at the server error log to find out what has actually gone wrong.

Don't use @ when you're trying to debug a script, it will hide errors that you want to see.

So I did make the move into removing the @ from the file, and went to check and see what specific errors were occurring, but when I check the server log to see, it doesn't show up the error tied to the timestamp to the time in which the error occurred. It only presents past errors that were present.

You haven't provided the PHP code that's causing the problem, you've only showed us how you connect to the database server and select a database. Show the rest of the code and maybe someone can help. What debugging have you done? For example sticking echo and exit in various places along the code to see how far it gets.

Actually, I did provide the PHP code directly tied to my current issue, as it is specifically shown in my post. The problem occurs at this specific line:
 $DBconnect = @mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password);
